# Why Doesn't Lightning Properly Refresh Page When Leads Are Converted in Trigger Context?

Tags: lightning-experience, lead-conversion, triggercontext

I'm surprised I don't see this mentioned anywhere, but when you convert a lead in trigger context after it is manually updated in the UI, SF throws: "Sorry, we encountered an unexpected error. Please try reloading the page" - even though there *wasn't* actually any error, and the lead converted just fine. When you take that extra step and refresh the page, only then do you see the converted contact.

The user sees the error message first though, and has no idea what happened. In Classic, the user would be shown a simple page explaining that the lead was converted and providing links to the converted contact, account, and opp. In Lightning it's completely unhandled, and it seems there is nothing you can do about it except change your business process entirely to take the lead conversion out of trigger context, by creating a button, doing the conversion async, or something else.

Is there a better solution I'm not seeing? Aren't hundreds of companies migrating to lightning dealing with this same issue?

[image]

Comment: As a matter of interest, which phase do you process the conversion in the trigger (before or after)?

Comment: After - we need to use the IDs of the newly created contact and account.

Comment: Just bumping this one, I'm wondering if the masses are all staring at this error every day and hopelessly refreshing their pages all the time. Seems crazy.

Also I believe conversion can only be done after update, before update is not allowed.